# Community User Login

Tags: community

We have set of community users in SF. What we require is  when the user enters credential in our system,we want to validate against SF.Is their simple way using saop api to check if the user exists in SF and get the object Id without using oauth2 based redirection.

Regards
Raghav

Answer (score 0):

Will [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_oauth_and_connected_apps.htm) flow not work for you ? It is username and password oauth flow, and a recognised method to use.